I cannot save the output of snic segmentation
This is my fist algorithm in GEE. I am trying to write snic akgorithm to get 6-band-segmented image. I cannot save the result of snic segmentation to Google Drive. How to I save the segemented image having with all bands value.Also when I use reproject, snic does not work.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle( 32.98148305276047,39.96525705731574,32.98265249589096,39.96599300698047 );

//stack
R = R.toFloat()
G = G.toFloat()
B = B.toFloat()
NIR = NIR.toFloat()
nDSM = nDSM.toFloat()
NDVI = NDVI.toFloat()
var stack = ee.Image.cat(R, G, B, NIR, NDVI, nDSM);
var TrueColor432 = stack.select(['b1','b1_1','b1_2'])
var TrueColor432Vis = {
 min :2691,
 max:65535,
};
Map.addLayer (TrueColor432, TrueColor432Vis, 'True color (432)')
var stack1 = stack.clip(geometry).select('b1', 'b1_1', 'b1_2', 'b1_3', 'b1_4', 'b1_5')
// Apply the SNIC algorithm to the image.
var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(50);
var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
 image: stack1,
 compactness: 0.1,
 connectivity: 8,
 neighborhoodSize: 20,
 size: 30,
 seeds: seeds
})
// Display the clusters.
var clusters = snic.select ('clusters');
Map.centerObject(geometry); // Haritayı geometriye odakla
Map.addLayer(clusters.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'clusters');
//Map.addLayer(snic.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'clusters');
Export.image.toDrive({
 image :clusters,
 description : 'clusters',
 fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
 region:geometry,
})





